# Do only Gaudiya Vaishnavites recognize different forms (not avataras) of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, gaudiya-vaishnavism

AFAIK, Other Vaishnavite sects don't say much (if anything) about Garbhodakaśāyī Vishnu and Ksirodakaśāyī Vishnu.

Only Gaudiya scripture seems to talk about these forms of Vishnu.